# Qt : How can I make a layout section stop expanding once the widgets its hosting stops expanding too

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qt-designer

I am trying the following experiment:

I have two `QpushButtons`, say `PushA` and `PushB`. Now `PushA` is in a `QHBoxLayout` and `PushB` is also in its own `QHBoxLayout`.  Both these horizontal layouts are in another `QHBoxLayout` layout; lets call it `HorizontalParentLayout`. Here is where the problem starts. `HorizontalParentLayout` has a layout stretch factor of `1,4` and `PushA` has a maximum width of `100`.  When the `HorizontalParentLayout` is stretched the horizontal layout hosting `PushA` also grows whereas `PushA` grows to a certain size (maximum size) then stops.  If I continue expanding `HorizontalParentLayout` the layout hosting `PushA` continues growing.  This is shown in the diagram below.  The purple arrows show that the layout is growing whereas the widget `Pushbutton` is fixed. I do not want this to happen. How can I make a layout section stop expanding once the widgets its hosting stops expanding two. This is what the image looks like

[image]

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The layout on the left grows because you have set it to do that. That's what `layoutStretch` does.

Try setting the stretch factor on the `HorizontalParentLayout` to 0, 4 (i.e. so that the first column has no stretch).